# how can i read PDF books with page curl animation in android?

Tags: android, pdf, animation

I am new to android.. i am going to develop an application related to reading pdf books with page curl animation. i applied this page curl animation to images which are stored in drawable folder, but i am unable to apply to pdf books.. so, any one can suggest me how to do ?

thankyou  in advance

Comment: Use any third party library to convert pdf to images then apply page curl animation to those images..:-)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757434/how-to-convert-pdf-into-image

Comment: @koti if you solve your problem please put your code or steps .

Comment: how to apply page curl for dynamic data views from server.without set data to view is there any way to capture the screen or bitmap thing plsease give some idea.now we are using flip animation.